# Deployment on github of a hexo blog

Tags: github, hexo

I created a repository on github and I would like to publish a blog created with hexo.
The html address of my repository is:

```
https://github.com/<my account name>/<my blog name>
```

The html address of my blog is:

```
https://<my account name>.github.io/<my blog name>/
```

I am using the plugin hexo-deployer git. I configure _config.yml like this:

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repos: git@github.com:<my account name>/<my account name>.github.io/<my blog name>.git
  branch: master
  message: "{{ now('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') }}"
```

But that doesn't work !

> INFO  Deploying: git
>   You have to configure the deployment settings in _config.yml first!

What is wrong in my syntax ?

Thank you by advance,

Answer (score 1):

If not answering late ...

Most of the articles on the internet on this topic (deploying a Hexo blog) suggest deploying with `hexo-deployer` plugin, either to *master* branch, or *gh-pages* branch.
But, with GitHub Pages there is a much simpler way, that doesn't require hexo-deployer plugin, and not even having other Git branches (other than *master* branch).

In your blog-level `_config.yml file`, set the `public_dir: docs`. This means that when you generate your blog content, it will be placed in the *docs* folder (on the *master* branch). Simply push the code to GitHub.

Now, you need to tell GitHub Pages server where your blog content to read from. In the GitHub repository, go to the *Settings* tab, and scroll down to the GitHub Pages section. As the Source, select the option: *master branch /docs folder*

You can find a more thorough explanation on this process [here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/deploying-hexo-blog-to-github-pages/)